# Evaluating $\int_{0}^{1} x^m \ln^\alpha(x) dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Honestly, I am asked to think about $$\int_{0}^{1} x^m \ln^\alpha(x) dx$$ And I applied all methods I know. I doubt if this integral makes sense either. If it is replicate, plz inform me to omit the question soon. Thanks.

Comment: This is annoying: why the downvote?!

Comment: I don't think this can be evaluated in elementary terms unless I'm overlooking something.

Comment: You might note that $\ln(x) < 0$ for $0 < x < 1$, so you need to use complex numbers to make sense of $(\ln x)^x$.

Comment: Babak, may I ask why were you asked to think about this?

Comment: A more conventional request would be the integral $\int_0^1 x^n \ln x\,dx$.

Comment: If you do allow complex numbers, the integrals certainly "make sense", i.e. converge, for $m > -1$.  Note that $\ln(x)^x = e^{x \ln(\ln x)}$

Comment: Thanks for all comments. Yes I know that integral GEdgar. I were asked this written in an diffrental Equation book by someone. I didn't see such this Integral before. Maybe it was recorded wrong. Sorry if I made you bad feelings.

Comment: Babak, was it *printed* in the book, if so which book is it? Otherwise I think you should just skip that comment.

Comment: @BabakSorouh If you change $\log(x)^x$ to $\log(x)^\alpha$, then Gamma comes in, otherwise I don't know.

Comment: Maybe, it is $\alpha$ and not $x$ in the exponent - they are pretty similar in certain fonts...

Comment: @AD.: Thank you Sir for the time. Thanks.

Comment: @BabakSorouh It might be good to leave the original post as it was written, and then put the update at the bottom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1x^m\,\log^\alpha(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_{-\infty}^0u^\alpha\,e^{(m+1)u}\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=(-1)^\alpha(m+1)^{-\alpha-1}\int_0^{\infty}t^\alpha e^{-t}\mathrm{d}t\\
&=(-1)^\alpha(m+1)^{-\alpha-1}\Gamma(\alpha+1)
\end{align}
$$